# Convert from using 3 identical SQL params to 1

Tags: java, sql, mysql, spring-security

I'm using the Java spring framework for security.  My pre-existing table layout differs from spring's expected, but I'm allowed to specify a custom authorities-by-username query on the jdbc-user-service.  The problem is that this query expects only a single parameter (?) in the SQL statement.  Basically, if the user exists in the users table at all, they should get 'ROLE_USER'.  If they exist in the auth table as 'S', they should get 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_LICENSEE' and 'ROLE_SYSADMIN'.  If they exist in the auth table as 'L', they should get both 'ROLE_LICENSEE', and 'ROLE_USER'.

```
SELECT U.email AS 'username', 'ROLE_USER' AS 'authority' FROM users U WHERE U.email=**?**
UNION
SELECT U.email AS 'username', 'ROLE_LICENSEE' AS 'authority' 
  FROM users U, auth_sys A 
 WHERE U.user_id=A.user_id AND A.auth_type IN ('L', 'S') AND U.email=**?**
UNION
SELECT U.email AS 'username', 'ROLE_ADMIN' AS 'authority' 
  FROM users U, auth_sys A 
 WHERE U.user_id=A.user_id AND A.auth_type='S' AND U.email=**?**;
```

My question is how can I reduce this from 3 (?)'s down to 1?

Comment: I don't recommend optimizing this into a single query.  As is, this is way easier to read & understand (thus, maintain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you won't be able to do that; since it sounds like you want a separate row for each user if they're in multiple roles.

If you can get by with only one row returned per user; and can assume that any Admin is also a licensee (evident by your where clause), you should be able to use a case statement and a left join.

Something like:

```
SELECT u.Email,
CASE WHEN a.user_id is null then 'Role_User'
WHEN a.auth_type = 'S' then 'Role_Admin'
WHEN a.auth_type = 'L' then 'Role_Licensee' end as 'authority'
FROM users u LEFT JOIN auth_sys a on u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE u.email = **?**
```

Granted; i'm not completely familiar with the table structure, so it might require a little tweaking; but that should be enough to get you started

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Spring Framework, you can use the Spring Framework to make your JDBC calls as well. Spring Framework has a [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) that allows you to name your JDBC parameters. So, you can create a named parameter called :emailAddress for example, and use the same parameter three times in the SQL, but pass it in only once into the template.

Comment: I'm using the jdbc user service, so it's straight-up sql.  I don't have acccess to JPA or hibernate and named params.  There's only a single numbered parameter that I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know is not possible. You have to use three query with union.